# twitter gem 2.0.2 ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter-gem

I just updated to rails 3.2 and twitter gem 2.0.2

Now when I start web server I get this message

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)):
 twitter (2.0.2) lib/twitter.rb:10:in `new'
```

`lib/twitter.rb:10` content

```
def new(options={})
  Twitter::Client.new(options)
end
```

Yesterday it worked with rails 3.1 and twitter gem 1.6.0

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this one to Gemfile, and then it worked.

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```